# Problems with pointers in a list

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, winsock

For some reason when I try and read a property of a pointer to an object(`GamePlayer`) within an `std::list` (`playerlist`)  it works at first, but when I try to access it later in another function I get a bunch of random numbers instead of the numbers for my client's socket. That was a mouthful, sorry.  I hope someone could shed some light on the situation. I will include a simplified version of the defective code.

```
class GameRoom  {

    list<GamePlayer*> playerlist;
    locigPort( LogicObj );
}


bool GameRoom::logicPort( LogicObj logit )  {   // This is room[1]

    list<GamePlayer*>::iterator it;

        for (it = playerlist.begin(); it != playerlist.end(); it++){  

                cout << "socket numbers " << (*it)->socketno << endl;  
                /* (*it)->socketno gives me a bunch of random numbers, 
                   not the socket numbers I was looking for! */
        }  

    return true;

}

bool RoomDB::addPlayer( GamePlayer *playerpoint )   {

    roomlist[1].playerlist.push_back( playerpoint );    
    // This adds the player object to the Gameroom object

    cout << "player point " << playerpoint->socketno << " roomno: " << roomno;  
    // This shows everything should be ok so far

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Check what happens with your sockets in between your good reading and the bad reading. If you can dereference the pointer, there's probably nothing wrong with the list.

Comment: @Roland: This kind of error can be diagnosed from an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that you're calling `addPlayer` with a pointer than becomes invalid by the time you call `logicPort`. One possibility is that you call `addPlayer` with the address of an object on the stack, and the object disappears when the stack is unwound.

**edit** The problem is right here:

```
bool PlayerDB::addPlayer( int sid, GamePlayer tempplayer ) {
   ...
   roomman.addPlayer( &tempplayer, tempplayer.roomno );
}
```

`PlayerDB::addPlayer` takes the second argument by value. This means that it gets a copy that exists for the lifetime of the method. You then take the pointer to that copy, and add it to the list. Once `PlayerDB::addPlayer` returns, the pointer becomes invalid.

It's hard to suggest a good fix without seeing more code. One possibility is to make `PlayerDB::addPlayer` take a pointer as its second argument, *and make sure you don't repeat the same mistake one level up the call chain*.

An even better possibility is to turn `playerlist` into `list<GamePlayer>`: from your code there doesn't appear to be any need for the list to contain *pointers*. This will simplify things greatly.

Comment: tempplayer.socketno = sid;
 // Add a player to the room
 roomman.addPlayer( &tempplayer, tempplayer.roomno );

Comment: @RolandSams: Still need more context. What is `tempplayer`, an object on the stack?

Comment: sorry I'm new can you tell me how to format code in my replies?

Comment: @RolandSams: You can use backticks (`\``) for short code snippets. Long snippets are better posted as part of your question (which you can edit) rather than comments.

Comment: `bool PlayerDB::addPlayer( int sid, GamePlayer tempplayer ) {  tempplayer.socketno = sid; PlayerDBint[sid] = tempplayer; // Add a player to the room roomman.addPlayer( &tempplayer, tempplayer.roomno ); cout << "Player name " << tempplayer.name << " has logged on" << endl; return true; }`

Comment: @RolandSams: Like @aix said, you put an object on the stack in the list. The variable `tempplayer` is just a temporary variable on the stack, and when the `addPlayer` function returns the object is destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I need pointers because it just works out better for my program later on... Long story.

Comment: @Roland: no, you need to understand how to use C++ properly, without using pointers for everything everywhere. :)

Comment: Thank you aix you were right.  The object went out of scope once the function exited.  I made the corrections and it works fine now.